# matplotlib polar plot scientific notation

Tags: matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I am trying to draw a polar plot with matplotlib and would like to do the following:
a) show tick labels with scientific notation
b) show radius circles at specified intervals.

Can anyone give me advice on how to do a) and b) with the code below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

theta =[np.pi/3, np.pi/3]
theta2 =[np.pi/6, np.pi/6]

r = [0.0, 8.0e-04]
r2 = [0.0, 7.0e-04]
ax.plot(theta, r, 'r-', label ='Observed')
ax.plot(theta2, r2, 'b-', label ='Simulated')

ax.grid(True)

ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.25),
          ncol=3, fancybox=True, shadow=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your `legend` call doesn't work because of `ncol`.

Comment: @Adobe You're right the legend call isn't exactly working right, but when I tried it the legend was actually there but it was outside the visible figure, you start to see it if you resize the figure to be itty bitty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For specifying location of radial ticks, it is very simple - you can just set rticks:

```
ax.set_rticks([0.0002, 0.0004, 0.0006, 0.0008])
```

There are a couple of options for the formatting, it depends on how exactly you want the ticks to be displayed.  The default formatter will automatically switch to scientific for large and small numbers.  If you want to change its threshold for what it considers "small", you can do that by modifying the yaxis formatter (the y axis is the radial axis):

```
ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_powerlimits((-3,4)) # Things smaller than 1e-3
                                                       # will be in scientific
                                                       # notation
```

However, that looks a bit funny to me, it puts the little "1e-4" in the upper left of the plot.

So, if you want to force the current radial ticks to be scientific notation where they are, one way is to use your own format for them.  The following uses `FormatStrFormatter`:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
# plotting code here
frmtr = ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%4.1e')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(frmtr)
```

There are plenty of options available via `matplotlib.ticker` if this doesn't do exactly what you wanted.  The second formatting option give me this:
[image: outputplot]